# Sanitize help on Raw sql

Tags: sql, cakephp, sanitize

I have some complex queries in my plugin which require me to use the `->query()` and not the `->find()` methods.

I couldn't understand how to sanitize the raw sql so I guessed someone here can guide me.

So the first step is to include the `App:import("sanitize");` before the declaration of the class.

Now let's say I have this :

`$query = $this->Mytable->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE " . $WHERECLAUSE . ";");`

Can some one help me out in sanitizing my query as i got completely lost in the cookbook.

Thanks for your help, it is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this: Sanitize::clean($query, $options)

Comment: hi,thanks for the quick reply. What goes in the $options variable?

Comment: Ok so if I set up my database variable in app/Config/database.php to $mydb, do i set it like this Sanitize::clean($query, $mydb);

Comment: Which version of cake are you using? The "App::import()" syntax above is deprecated since 2.0 and the folder structure you just have mentioned is Cake 2.X. 
To answer your question: No. You have to provide a string. In this case 'mydb'.
What exaclty are you trying to get from the database? The find() method is mightier than you might think. Maybe we can help you out with that one instead of messing around with this manual sanitizing.

Comment: Hi. I have a couple of queries where I used the find, however, this particular query, I have joins with 6 different tables, concatenations and the query method would be much easier. All I want is to prevent sql injection in my query

Answer (score 0):

Sanitize::clean is used for values / whole arrays such as $this->data.

```
$WHERECLAUSE = Sanitize::clean($whereclause, array('escape'));
$query = $this->Mytable->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE " . $WHERECLAUSE . ";");
```

That'll do the trick.

```
array('escape')
```

is used for SQL statements.